# Bake ONE material with two image textures into a texture

Tags: materials, texture-baking, unity

I have a book page. There is one Material on that page with 2 image textures, the first one is the paper material, the second one is text, well-positioned on the page.

I am able to bake it correctly but the first image texture (the paper material) is not visible. The result is only the text with black.

What can I do against that? I cannot find a workaround. 
I need to do this for unity.

Let me know if you need anything to answer this.

Comment: How did you mix the two textures onto the same object?
A screenshot of the shader nodes structure might help....